# Roll Logs Into Specific Directory Log4j2

Tags: log4j2, relative-path

### Goal: Have Log4j2:

1. Create the root "logs" directory if it doesn't exist.
2. Create an "archive" directory if it doesn't exist so `RollingFile` appender can save the rolled logs.

**Expected Result:**

```
..\logs\MyLog.log
..\logs\archive\MyLog_2022-03-03_1.log
..\logs\archive\MyLog_2022-03-03_2.log
..\logs\archive\MyLog_2022-03-03_3.log
.
.
..\logs\archive\MyLog_2022-03-03_20.log
```

I'm expecting the creation of "logs" & "archive" directories in case they aren't there on start-up/1st roll.

##### Actual Results:

**Regarding the "logs" directory:**

- if the "logs" directory **doesn't exist** prior to start-up then system continues running without logging anything or creating the directory.
- if the "logs" directory **exists** prior to start-up then it saves the main log file to it.

**Regarding the "archive" directory for rolling logs:**

- if the "archive" directory **doesn't exist** prior to start-up then it is created, the system crashes and an exception is thrown.
- if the "logs" directory **exists** prior to start-up then the system crashes and an exception is thrown.

#### What I have tried:

1. Replacing the properties with their actual hard-coded values.
2. Replacing the path with "`./`" at the beginning.
3. Replacing the path with "`../`" at the beginning.
4. Replacing the beginning of the path with various possible [Lookups](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html) from Log4j2's documentation.
5. Hard-coding the full-path, which worked but **is not an option to use as it will change according to the customer's installation location.**

**Configuration:**

```xml
<Properties>
    <Property name="log.dir">logs</Property>
    <Property name="log.file">MyLog</Property>
    <Property name="pattern">%d %-5p [%t] %c{2}:%L - %m%n</Property>
</Properties>

<RollingFile name="MainLog" fileName="${log.dir}/${log.file}.log" filePattern="${log.dir}/archive/${log.file}_%d{MM-dd-yyyy}_%i.log.gz">
    <PatternLayout pattern="${pattern}" />
    <Policies>
        <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="20 MB" />
    </Policies>
    <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" />
</RollingFile>
```

##### Research:

I've tried various Google searches and looked into many Stackoverflow questions, I will not be listing them here as they do not include any actual relevant data. 
Weirdly enough, I wasn't able to find any similar question.

**What am I missing?**

Comment: Probably you have permission problems. Run your application with `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to check why the directories are not created.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz the directory is created but then an exception saying cannot read the directory is thrown.

Comment: Check the Windows permissions on that folder. Does the user running the Java application have enough permissions? You don't mention what application are you running, but e.g. Tomcat as a Windows service usually runs as a very low privilege `LocalService` user.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz thanks for the input. I've checked that. Everything seems fine.
Also, I am wondering, in case it actually was a permissions problem (which I don't think it is) but then how can I control it if I do not know where the application is being deployed?